# Flutter - Progress Bar from the Rows background color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've got row with some text on the left and right side of it. center is expanded so both texts are located at left, right corners.

```
Row( children: [  Text('left Text'),
 Expanded(child: Text('')),
Text('right Text'
),
]),
```

Now I I wrap this Row in a Container with color then the whole row will get background color.

```
Container( color: Colors.green,
child:MY_ROW()
)
```

What I want now is to put some background color  not on the entire row but controllable part of it, to make a progress bar. is that possible ? Also if this progress bar could be animated that would be a plus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _percent = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MyCustomProgressBar(percent: _percent),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => _percent < 100 ? _percent += 10 : null),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double percent;
  const MyCustomProgressBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.percent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCustomProgressBar> createState() => _MyCustomProgressBar();
}

class _MyCustomProgressBar extends State<MyCustomProgressBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 70,
      child: Stack(
        //direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          AnimatedContainer(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100 * widget.percent,
            color: Colors.green,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(widget.percent.toString()),
              const Text('Right text'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can it be done without any buttons ? I mean just 1 time animation onLoad. without any buttons. Is there a place where I can test this code ? some online editor ?

Comment: You can test it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)

Comment: No I do'nt want centered. I want  the progress bar to be the size I choose. 30% or 50% or 70% depends on which number I send to it\

Comment: Tryied your code in dart pad.
Problem is that green background takes part only between texts. 
What I want is background color must have access to all width. So despite there is text blocks  in this row, background color must have possibility to fill the entire row

Comment: What I'm saying is that If I use 100% then green line must be from the left to the right even below text blocks. Is that possible ?

Comment: Try please I edit code in answer